# How to use Pandas to adjust data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the data frame below
    [image]

using python pandas to the next data frame below

[image]

Pardon me but I am very very new to Pandas. The table has already been imported to a data frame called filterframe.

Comment: Small advice - [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date','County'], var_name='situtation', value_name='score')
print (df1)

          date      County     situtation  score
0   22/01/2000  Buckingham    Outstanding   20.0
1   22/01/2000      London    Outstanding   46.0
2   24/06/2000  Manchester    Outstanding   13.0
3   02/07/2000    Ipswitch    Outstanding   66.0
4    04/0/2000     Crawley    Outstanding   34.0
5   22/01/2000  Buckingham           Okay   34.0
6   22/01/2000      London           Okay   35.0
7   24/06/2000  Manchester           Okay    6.0
8   02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Okay    5.0
9    04/0/2000     Crawley           Okay   88.0
10  22/01/2000  Buckingham           Good    9.0
11  22/01/2000      London           Good    3.0
12  24/06/2000  Manchester           Good    2.0
13  02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Good   66.0
14   04/0/2000     Crawley           Good   56.0
15  22/01/2000  Buckingham       Inferior    6.0
16  22/01/2000      London       Inferior    NaN
17  24/06/2000  Manchester       Inferior    NaN
18  02/07/2000    Ipswitch       Inferior    NaN
19   04/0/2000     Crawley       Inferior    NaN
20  22/01/2000  Buckingham  Very Inferior   65.0
21  22/01/2000      London  Very Inferior    7.0
22  24/06/2000  Manchester  Very Inferior    7.0
23  02/07/2000    Ipswitch  Very Inferior   56.0
24   04/0/2000     Crawley  Very Inferior   57.0
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - by default `dropna=True`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['date','County']).stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['date','County','situtation','score']
print (df1)
          date      County     situtation  score
0   22/01/2000  Buckingham    Outstanding   20.0
1   22/01/2000  Buckingham           Okay   34.0
2   22/01/2000  Buckingham           Good    9.0
3   22/01/2000  Buckingham       Inferior    6.0
4   22/01/2000  Buckingham  Very Inferior   65.0
5   22/01/2000      London    Outstanding   46.0
6   22/01/2000      London           Okay   35.0
7   22/01/2000      London           Good    3.0
8   22/01/2000      London  Very Inferior    7.0
9   24/06/2000  Manchester    Outstanding   13.0
10  24/06/2000  Manchester           Okay    6.0
11  24/06/2000  Manchester           Good    2.0
12  24/06/2000  Manchester  Very Inferior    7.0
13  02/07/2000    Ipswitch    Outstanding   66.0
14  02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Okay    5.0
15  02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Good   66.0
16  02/07/2000    Ipswitch  Very Inferior   56.0
17   04/0/2000     Crawley    Outstanding   34.0
18   04/0/2000     Crawley           Okay   88.0
19   04/0/2000     Crawley           Good   56.0
20   04/0/2000     Crawley  Very Inferior   57.0
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index(['date','County']).stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['date','County','situtation','score']
print (df1)
          date      County     situtation  score
0   22/01/2000  Buckingham    Outstanding   20.0
1   22/01/2000  Buckingham           Okay   34.0
2   22/01/2000  Buckingham           Good    9.0
3   22/01/2000  Buckingham       Inferior    6.0
4   22/01/2000  Buckingham  Very Inferior   65.0
5   22/01/2000      London    Outstanding   46.0
6   22/01/2000      London           Okay   35.0
7   22/01/2000      London           Good    3.0
8   22/01/2000      London       Inferior    NaN
9   22/01/2000      London  Very Inferior    7.0
10  24/06/2000  Manchester    Outstanding   13.0
11  24/06/2000  Manchester           Okay    6.0
12  24/06/2000  Manchester           Good    2.0
13  24/06/2000  Manchester       Inferior    NaN
14  24/06/2000  Manchester  Very Inferior    7.0
15  02/07/2000    Ipswitch    Outstanding   66.0
16  02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Okay    5.0
17  02/07/2000    Ipswitch           Good   66.0
18  02/07/2000    Ipswitch       Inferior    NaN
19  02/07/2000    Ipswitch  Very Inferior   56.0
20   04/0/2000     Crawley    Outstanding   34.0
21   04/0/2000     Crawley           Okay   88.0
22   04/0/2000     Crawley           Good   56.0
23   04/0/2000     Crawley       Inferior    NaN
24   04/0/2000     Crawley  Very Inferior   57.0
```

Comment: Jezrael, You are a master! I cant believe the speed at which you solved this....I'm so screaming here. How long will it take me to get used to the pandas library. I only just started learning pandas this week!

Comment: Supeer, I think pandas is very nice and good library with perfect docs ;)

Comment: Do you have a forum where you can teach or a form of contact?

Comment: No, I have no forum. But in my opinion the best for learning are tutorials [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)